push notification: confusion with category or type os subtitle of message or anything else
Could anybody elaborate on this sutuation please.
When I receive a push notification from apps in my iphone I could see in notification list:
AppName1
Message
AppName2
Notification
AppName1
Notification
AppName4
4 Transations
When I do a long press on push - these words Notification/Message are dissapeared and just shows to me a real message with actions that I could do or notification without any actions.
What is these Notification, Transaction, Message in terms of Push Notifications?
how could I control them over fcm for example?
I don't have code.
I got this push:

You could see a Notification subtitle. But it could be Message or Transaction.
If I do a long tap on that push it will be transformed into

Notification word is gone and not shown anymore.

Please post image and code.

@BobSmith added images.

You can group related notifications together using notification categories on iOS 14 and above. This might be how the "Transactions" label is appearing on your device. Its called notification category Check these links https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/managing-notifications .... https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications and https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client

@BobSmith thanks! another question - does it support somehow localization?)

Sahka That's great now you got the picture how notification works. About localisation yes it supports. Let me post a detailed answer for this.
